# got you? so difficult to understand this sentence

Tags: grammar

Situation in the movie - 'Blended' (2014)

woman yet to come to meeting place for blind date.
man has just arrived and ordered dishes.
and in a minute woman finally arrived.

Man: (staring on TV) Got you, uh, Buffalo shrimp with the sauce on the side.
They'll do that for me here. I didn't know how you took it so...

Woman: You realize that you're not actually looking at my face right now.

==================

1. What does " Got you" means in that sentence ?
2. what does "it" and "so"  indicate as in "how you took it so" ?
   It doesn't make sense the whold meaning as well.
3. what does "on the side" means as in "with the sauce  on the side?
4. " You realize ~~ " means "you will be realizing soon" ?
   how can 'a declarative sentence indicate imperative nuance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He has ordered the shrimp for her, with the sauce served separately in case she doesn't like sauce on her shrimps. He doesn't know 'how she takes it' (the dish) - with sauce or without. "So..." just means "so I didn't order them with sauce poured over".

"You realize" is just an informal way of asking "Do you realize...?"

Comment: thank you for your help!